# Why is my neglected circular saw smoking and screeching?

Tags: circular-saw, smoke

I had this  Evolution Fury 1B circular saw that I bought to start my DIY wood repair. I barely used it, but it got soaked down as the garage leaked. Now when I use it it sparks at the end, it was sparking when new too - but i now feel it sparks more and it also smells, as if rubber burning. I want to repair myself. Please guide me. It is also making a bit of a screechy noise. Assuming I'd damage the armature further I haven't used it since then a year ago. Just to clarify, i did not use it while wet, i dried it thoroughly for a few days before turning it on.What would need fixing?

Comment: Almost certainly non-economically sensible to repair, particularly if you have a Habitat for Humanity "Re-Store" in your area. $20 got me a perfectly nice working used Makita at our local one when my old Porter-Cable burnt its armature, which part (alone) cost more than the whole saw did new, and might not have been the only bad part.

Comment: it sounds like it may have gotten wet ... if you let it sit for a year, then it is probably thoroughly rusted

Comment: Oh! It was a little rusted.I opened it to dry and sand the rust away, as much as I could, which was not much & let it dry for months. Since I bought 2yrs ago around Easter holidays, I used it once just to trim the Xmas tree to fit the tree holder.although, I could buy a 2nd hand, I think some of them I couldn't trust what condition they could be in, others could be stolen goods, although I am on the lookout from today. Even if it means, changing the armature,i am keen to do it, provided I could get trustable parts here in the UK. So, please anyone who had repaired such a thing, please advise.

Comment: Probably need to replace motor, bearings, and switches.  Price 150% at least cost of saw.  Next saw, when it rains, bring it inside.

Comment: All my good tools - which are **not** top-of-the-line - but anything complex (e.g., battery or plug-in electric beyond just a simple light-on-an-extension-cord), I keep inside all the time. Adds to the clutter, but I know that outside (even in the shed) they just won't last.

Comment: When it was wet and the smoke came out last year. That is the magic smoke that electric appliances run on and once released it is rare to get them to work again.  In reality if the motor windings smoked because they were wet if dried out and it still smokes the windings are usually shorted and the armature is toast. An electrician would use a tool called a megger to test the windings. This is a high voltage ohm meter to check for leakage in the windings to ground. If the motor kind of runs but the noise it could need lubrication but if more smoke comes out of the motor time for a new armature.

Comment: Using your favorite internet search engine, type in `<make> <model> repair`. Odds are good you'll find a variety of YT videos explaining _general_ circular saw repair, some about _your_ particular make/model, and several sources of parts that will fit your saw.

Comment: Thankyou all for your replies.